# how to test a formula to see if a particular value is used in that formula

Tags: excel, vba

From a large worksheet, I'm trying to find out if a particular value is used in that formula.

E.g. formula:

```
 (In cell C1)=A1+B1*.75
```

I want to check if .75 is used in the formula (which is 75%)
There are 1000's of record would it be possible to check the entire column C

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub findIt()
    mesage = ""
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.HasFormula Then
            v = r.Formula
            If InStr(v, ".75") > 0 Then
                mesage = mesage & vbCrLf & r.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox mesage
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfect. Just an addition. Instead of getting a message can the cells that use (.75) be shaded with a color.

Answer (score 0):

This version hi-lights the cell:

```
Sub findIt()
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.HasFormula Then
            v = r.Formula
            If InStr(v, ".75") > 0 Then
                r.Interior.Color = 65535
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```